# Bash: Path to symlink which calls this script

Tags: bash, scripting, symlink

I have the following situation:

- I have a script with a path of: `/usr/local/bin/rsnapshot.period`
- I want to have symlinks to it in various `/etc/cron.[period]/` directories, like `/etc/cron.hourly/rsnapshot`

I'd like to have the script look up the full path to the symlink, and pull out the [period] part, so I can feed it to rsnapshot.

I can do all the text hacking.  The problem I'm having trouble with is getting the path to the calling symlink from within the bash script.  `$0` seems to point to `/usr/local/bin/rsnapshot.period`

Is there a better way to get this info?

Comment: Adding your OS might help get a better answer - on Ubuntu `$0` is the name the script was called with. If all of yours give the "actual script" then my guess is: a) it isn't being called how you think. b) your OS is [partly?] to blame.

Comment: I have scripts `~/bin/Cron/hourly`, `~/bin/Cron/daily`, `~bin/Cron/weekly`, etc that are all aymlinks to the same script, `~/bin/Cron/runcron`.  I have had no problem with identifying which name was used on Solaris, HP-UX, AIX, Mac OS X, Ubuntu Linux, RedHat Linux — to name the systems that I currently use.  Which system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> `$0` seems to point to `/usr/local/bin/rsnapshot.period`

`$0` is set by the calling program in its `exec*()` call, as the first word of the `arg` argument or the first element of the `argv` argument. If you feel that the tool you're using is setting this value incorrectly then you should open a bug with the developer.

In the meantime, using a hardlink instead of a symlink will allow you to detect the script name properly, but will break if you aren't careful with the tool you use to edit the main script.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem wasn't that $0 was incorrect - it was pointing to the right place.  However, as I was trying to get the *absolute* path of it, I was using 'realpath' before it, which resolved symlinks.

Passing realpath the '-s' fixed it.  Here's my test script and the output of it:

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo \$0: $0
echo realpath -s \$0: $(realpath -s $0)
echo readlink -e:  $(readlink -e $0)
```

Executed:

```
$0: ./rsnapshot
realpath -s $0: /etc/cron.hourly/rsnapshot
readlink -e: /usr/local/bin/rsnapshot.period
```